# list index out of range reading files

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am a beginner of python and would need some help. I have run into a problem when trying to manipulating some dat-files.

I have created 159 dat.files (`refitted_to_digit0_0.dat, refitted_to_digit0_1.dat, ...refitted_to_digit0_158.dat`) containing time series data of two columns (timestep, value) of 2999 rows. In my python program I have created a list of these files with `filelist_refit_0=glob.glob('refitted_to_digit0_*')
plist_refit_0=[]`

I now try to load the second column of each 159 files into the `plist_refit_0` so that each place in the list contains an array of 2999 values (second columns) that I will use for further manipulations. I have created a for-loop for this and use the `len(filelist_refit_0)` as the range for the loop. The length being 159 (number of files: 0-158).

However, when I run this I get an error message: `list index out of range`. 
I have tried with a lower range for the for-loop and it seems to work up until range 66 but not above that. `filelist_refit_0[66]` refer to file `refitted_to_digit0_158.dat` and `filelist_refit_0[67]` refer to `refitted_to_digit0_16.dat`. `filelist_refit_0[158]` refer to `refitted_to_digit0_99.dat`. Instead of being sorted in ascending order based on the value 0->158 I think the `plist_refit_0` have the files in ascending order based on the digits: refitted_to_digit0_0.dat first, then `refitted_to_digit0_1.dat`, then `refitted_to_digit0_10.dat`, then `refitted_to_digit0_100.dat`, then refitted_to_digit0_101.dat resulting in `refitted_to_digit0_158.dat` being on place 66 in the list. However, I still don't understand why the compiler interprets the index as being out of range above 66 when the length of the `filelist_refit_0` being 159 and there really are 159 files, no matter the order. If anyone can explain this and have some advice how to solve this problem, I highly appreciate it! Thanks for your help.

I have tried the following to understand the sorting:

```
print len(filelist_refit_0) => 159
print filelist_refit_0[66] => refitted_to_digit0_158.dat
print filelist_refit_0[67] => refitted_to_digit0_16.dat
print filelist_refit_0[158] => refitted_to_digit0_99.dat
print filelist_refit_0[0] => refitted_to_digit0_0.dat
```

I have "manually" loaded the files and it seems to work for most index e.g.

```
t, p = loadtxt(filelist_refit_0[65], usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
plist_refit_0.append(p)
t, p = loadtxt(filelist_refit_0[67], usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
plist_refit_0.append(p)
print plist_refit_0[0]
print plist_refit_0[1]
```

BUT it does not work for index66!:

```
t, p = loadtxt(filelist_refit_0[66], usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
plist_refit_0.append(p)
```

Then I get error: `list index out of range`.

As can be seen above it refers to `refitted_to_digit0_158.dat` which is the last file. I have looked into the file and it looks exactly the same as all the other files, which the same number of columns and raw-elements (2999). Why is this entry different?

Python 2:

```
filelist_refit_0 = glob.glob('refitted_to_digit0_*')
plist_refit_0 = []

for i in range(len(filelist_refit_0)):
    t, p = loadtxt(filelist_refit_0[i], usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
    plist_refit_0.append(p)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 107, in <module>
    t,p=loadtxt(filelist_refit_0[i],usecols=(0,1),unpack=True) 
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1092, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1012, in read_data
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: To be painfully certain it is not an issue with that one specific file can you temporarily replace the file `refitted_to_digit0_158.dat` with a copy of one of the working files renamed to `refitted_to_digit0_158.dat`?  My guess right now based on your error is that in your file you don't have both columns filled all the way to the bottom.  Checking with a renamed file that otherwise works would prove my guess wrong if the otherwise working file does not work under this name.

Comment: I did as you said and it works! I copied file 157 and renamed it to 158. Strange, it sees to be something wrong with file 158 but I haven't managed to spot any differences. Thanks a lot for your help!